# Log all AJAX request durations with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I need to measure the response times of all AJAX requests sent with jQuery, so if a request takes longer than [x] seconds, I can notify the user. However, I don't wish to abort the request, so I'm not using the `timeout` property of `$.ajaxSetup`. So I looked into `$.ajaxStart`, however it will only run if there aren't any other AJAX requests in progress. However, because I'm sending multiple requests asynchronously, it doesn't run but for one. What am I best to do?

Comment: Create a new `Date` right before the `$.ajax` call, then in the callback, create another `Date`, compare that to the one you created before.

Comment: It's in a large Backbone app, so your method won't be scalable at all to do it on individual instances

Comment: Hmm..interesting..damn, that's all I got. I'll keep thinking, maybe something will come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSend() method are executed at this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime;
vat endTime;
$.ajax({
  //whatever your code is
  beforeComplete:function()
  {
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
  }
  success: function() {
    var endTime = new Date().getTime(),
    total =  endTime - startTime;
    console.log(total);
  }
  afterComplete:function()
  {
     endTime = new Date().getTime();
   // alert(endTime-startTime)
   // log endTime-startTime
  }
});
```

Comment: yep , just another alternative , not the best one